# Vista Home Premium won't upload to websites

Tags: windows-vista, upload

I have a Sony Vaio notebook (VGN-FW31J) running Windows Vista Home Premium . I've had it over a year and file upload in a browser has never worked on any website in any browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome). I can select a file and the upload starts running but I always get a timeout. Sometimes it has worked once out of many attempts but only if the file is very small (< 50k). FTP **does** work.

I've tried the following:

- Disabling anti virus
- Disabling firewall

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem of losing packets. If to many packets are lost then you receive a timeout. The risk will be larger on larger files. That you have nor or only small problem on normal serving.

How is your laptop connected?

If it is WLAN and not a cable then you can have a problem with a bad connection. You can change the channel of your WLAN.

You can also use some bandwidth test web sides. To check your connection.